# How to get the values from JSON URL

Tags: shell, pentaho

I'm trying to fetch the yammer Followers using below rest API.

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json
```

Api contains details for each user. From this I need to extract followers count alone.

```
{"type":"user","id":1517006975,"network_id":461,"stats":{"following":0,"followers":0,"updates":0}}
```

Rate limit for per page is 50, as we have 100 000+ users I need to iterate 2000+ times to get the whole dump which is actually slow.

So I need method to directly extract the necessary data.

I am using shell script + pentaho .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options.

1. If you are bound to shell, you could run the json response through a series of sed silliness to get to a list that you can then parse more effectively with shell tools. something like: `curl http://foo.com | sed 's/,/\n/g'` 
   will get you something more row based, and then you can start to parse it out from there using more `sed` or `awk` or `cut` and `tr`.
2. look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)? it is a statically linked standalone c binary that allows really nice filtering of json